# how do i run over a too big string?

Tags: java, string

so ive been trying to run over an html file , finding a specific detail in it.

after i failed doing it with jsoup (as i thought then , cause jsoup just cant handle that handle that site) ive just downloaded the website into an html file and parsed it to a big String...
then , i found out that its probably not the jsoup that is messed up , but how big the string is.
seems like it stores it okay at first (i can see that the length is 600k chars) but cant really do more than that. when trying to reach into the string it breaks and i see only the end.

i wont show the code cause i dont want to reveal the work , but ill explain it like this- 
i get the content of the html into a string ,
i run on it trying to find a specific phrase , 
i fail because the string get cuts to the last bit of chars it can hold.

so my question is how do i make my string be able to store much more than its supposed to? / any other solution to my situation?

ive tried splitting the string into 20 substrings and it just messes the entire thing. i cant even cut it to bits before it messes up.

~~~~ so ive rewrote the important part , so you could show me whats wrong

```
File folder = new File("folderName");
    File[] filesList = folder.listFiles();
    List<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < filesList.length; i++) {
        if (filesList[i].isFile()) {
            File file = filesList[i];
            String content;

            try {
                // getting a string out of the HTML file
                content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8");

                String newSubString = content;
```

if ill system.out.print this , it will show me only from somewhere around the end.
aswell when i run on it , it will start run over the end.

Comment: The string is fine, but there's something wrong with something else in the code, but it's hard to say what, since you don't want to reveal it `:[`

Comment: 600k is not so big nowadays. Should not be a problem to handle that.

Comment: A string can get huge even with default memory settings. 600k chars is about 1.3MB in UTF-8. So it is the way you work with your data and not the data. http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/string_memory_usage.shtml

Comment: You say that you can call `length()` on the string and see that it has the 600k characters, but the problem comes when you "reach into the string". Can you say more about how you are reaching into it?

Comment: well what i am trying to do is finding an index of a phrase , so i could then pick it up into a list.

there are about 15 of these phrases each html file. 
the first one i find is one of the last ones.... 
or when i systemoutprint it , i can see that its not begining in the begining.

even when i dont do the entire loop mechanism around it , syso'ing  the string of one html file by its self works the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a StringBuilder instead.

Strings are immutable and therefore a new copy is made each time you append to a String.

StringBuilder is a lot more efficient as it is mutable and you can convert it to a String when you are finished modifying it using its toString() method.